# C++ - Time execution 0s with Chrono Library

Tags: c++, sorting, time, mergesort, c++-chrono

I'm sorting an array with merge sort. I use the Chrono library to measure the time, but, sometimes, the result is 0.

```
int main() {
    srand(50000);
    int A[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = rand();
    }

    cout << "Array non ordinato\n";
    Stampa(A, N);
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    QuickSort(A, 0, N - 1);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;
    cout << "\nArray ordinato\n";
    Stampa(A, N);
    cout << "Elapsed time in nanoseconds : "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count()
         << " ns" << endl;
    cout << "Elapsed time in milliseconds : "
         << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
         << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << "s";
}
```

I defined `N` with `#define N 300`.

If `N` is `300`, elapsed time (nanosecond, millisecond or second) is `0`. If I increment `N`, I have an elapsed time greater than zero. I need time for small arrays too. How could I fix it?

Comment: Seriously, 300 Items is hardly anything to time, thus it wouldn't be surprising that the result is 0.  You should be running tests with thousands, maybe a million or so items.

Comment: What's the precision of the system clock? On my system, `system_clock::now()` returns a `std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000>>>>`, which is measuring things in microseconds.

Comment: Try std::chrono::steady_clock instead of std::chrono::system clock.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more precision for smaller N sorting, I recommend using the [high resolution clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) instead of the system clock.

Comment: And even then you may find the resolution insufficient to represent the time involved. High resolution clock gives you the best available resolution, and that best resolution can still be tens of milliseconds on a desktop PC.

Comment: Right, unfortunately if they're, for some reason, stuck with low N's then this is the best chance they've got. Can't invent a sub-nano clock for OP :)

Comment: @user4581301 - in the case of Windows, QueryPerformanceCounter, is a sub-microsecond counter. On my system, it's running at a bit over 3 Mega hz on Win 7, and about 3.5 Giga hz (cpu clock speed) on Win XP. Visual Studio 2015 and later fixed chrono's steady_clock to use the same counter as QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: Good clocks are out there, but is the chrono implementation using one? I recently had to back off on a change because I couldn't get better than the craptastic 64 Hz Windows tick if I stuck to pure C++.

Comment: @user4581301 - as commented above, this was an issue with Visual Studio prior to 2015 if using std::chrono, but never an issue if using QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: In my case it was mingw. I can't remember the version. I may have been trapped into using an antique to support a GCC 4.8 application.

Comment: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is an alias to either `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::system_clock`, or even some other clock, I guess. When you are measuring time like in the question, you need to use `std::chrono::steady_clock`. Quoting from the standard: Objects of `class high_resolution_clock` represent clocks with the shortest tick period. `high_resolution_clock` may be a synonym for `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are measuring time like in the question, you need to use `std::chrono::steady_clock` or any other clock where the `is_steady` property is `true`. `std::chrono::system_clock` is using the wall-clock which may change at any given time. This is the purpose of the `std::chrono::system_clock`: to represent the current time for the system.

You probably also want to use a higher number of elements to see any meaningful differences in time.

Although `std::chrono::high_resolution` clock is tempting going by it's name alone, it is worth noting that there is, technically, no high resolution clock in chrono. Rather, it is an alias to the clock that has the highest resolution available. Quoting from the standard:

> Objects of `class high_resolution_clock` represent clocks with the
>   shortest tick period. `high_resolution_clock` may be a synonym for
>   `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.

when we check the implementations we see that MSVC has the following:

```cpp
using high_resolution_clock = steady_clock;
```

while libstdc++-v3 has:

```cpp
/**
 *  @brief Highest-resolution clock
 *
 *  This is the clock "with the shortest tick period." Alias to
 *  std::system_clock until higher-than-nanosecond definitions
 *  become feasible.
*/
using high_resolution_clock = system_clock;
```